# In App Purchases Review Status

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, in-app-purchase

I have an app up for review that includes IAPs. The App has had the status of `In Review` for three days now. When I went to the IAP page in iTunesConnect, I noticed that all my IAPs had been changed to `Developer Action Needed`. When I clicked on each of the IAPs, the english language was highlighted and they were marked as `rejected`.

I went ahead a made a small change to each of the IAPs description and now all of them are in `Waiting for Review`. Today marks day two of the IAPs with the `Waiting for Review` status.

Is there something I need to do to get the review going? I have had no feedback from Apple and I am hesitant to upload a new binary, as that will push the review out for another week.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it takes time. Your in-app purchase should be approved before submitting your app to review. See [Average App Store Review Times](http://reviewtimes.shinydevelopment.com/) for waiting times.

Comment: Hello @Graham Miln I have a problem can you help here

Comment: Feel free to [ask a new question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to attract help.